# How to learn about Shimura varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, nt.number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good roadmap for learning Shimura curves?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11219/what-is-a-good-roadmap-for-learning-shimura-curves)

What's the best way (in your opinion) to learn the theory of Shimura varieties?

Comment: Duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11219/is-there-a-the-arithmetic-of-elliptic-curves-for-shimura-curves ?

Comment: While not identical, it seems close enough not to inspire a separate response from me, at least.  

Comment: I vote to close as duplicate. I also changed the title of the question linked to by David to make it reflect the question/answer more accurately.

Comment: @norondion, please don't take the closure personally. If the linked answer is not sufficient for some reason (e.g. it only deals with curves), you should just provide more background in the question body.

Comment: I think the questions are fairly different, if one is really about Shimura curves and the other really about general Shimura varieties.  If I have time in the next day or so, I will try to answer this (asuming it remains open).

Comment: I think I may have missed the Shimura *varieties* aspect of the question, so I have not voted to close.  An easy answer is to look at some of Milne's lecture notes and/or Deligne's paper _Travaux de Shimura_.  But I am curious to hear what Emerton has to say...

Comment: The subject of Shimura curves is a very special case of the subject of Shimura varieties; each has it's own focus, range of techniques, etc.    Perhaps the question is broad, but I don't think it is any broader than many other questions.  The answer to ``how do I learn about Shimura varieties'' will have very little in common with ``how do I learn Shimura curves''.  Thus I don't understand the judgement of those labelling it an exact duplicate, and have voted to reopen.